# MySQL - get all posts (distinct) with tags

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, distinct, pivot-table

I have this category_post_tag pivot table.

For example:

```
category_id         post_id         tag_ig
    1                   1              1
    1                   1              2
    1                   2              3
    1                   3              1
    1                   3              3
    2                   4              5
```

Now lets say i want to grab some posts, belonging to my first category id.

Then i would select all the posts from the this pivot table that has the category_id 1
and i would probably group them by post_id.

Result:

```
post_id: 1, 2, 3
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but i think its not so bad.

Ok, but my problem is when i want to know each tag belonging to that returned post.

So if i group_by post_id i will always have only one tag to one post.

Is there a way to get back all the tags belonging to one post, and still have a distinct post array?

Comment: Just out of idle curiousity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Strawberry this is how the categories, posts, and tags are connected in this blog engine.

Comment: That's fine. I just don't quite get why you want a result in this format. Or maybe I don't really understand what the desired result set should look like. To my mind, and to a rough approximation, there is no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT (or indeed CONCAT) is the correct answer. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: @Strawberry because the front-end uses a jquery plugin that shows/hides posts by tagids.

Comment: The front end uses jquery plug-in? So there's a front-end? So that front end is PHP? So do the whole processing thing there. Much more flexible, and scalable, AND it preserves the essential intelligence of the data!

Comment: Look, i need to pass the posts data to the view file for the front end guy in a way that he can then list them and add the tagids of a post on the li tag for sorting purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select post_id, 
       group_concat(tag_id) as tag_ids
from category_post_tag 
where category_id = 1
group by post_id
```

Comment: Thank you, that was great. Have a nice day. I will accept your answer as soon as the limit is over.